# How to justify a single flexbox item (override justify-content)

Tags: css, flexbox

You can override `align-items` with `align-self` for a flex item.
I am looking for a way to override `justify-content` for a flex item.

If you had a flexbox container with `justify-content:flex-end`, but you want the first item to be `justify-content: flex-start`, how could that be done?

Comment: Use `auto` margins. See box #26 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 778, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be `justify-self`, but you can achieve similar result setting appropriate `margin` to `auto`¹. E. g. for `flex-direction: row` (default) you should set `margin-right: auto` to align the child to the left.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 10px skyblue;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  background: tomato;
}
.justify-start {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block justify-start">justify-start</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

¹ This behaviour is [defined by the Flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins).

Comment: This technique is excellent and it also works in the vertical direction. For instance, you want the last element inside a fixed height container to stick to the bottom. You can use 
```
    .container { 
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start
    }
    .last-item {
      margin-top: auto 
    }
```

Comment: @Pavlo Any explanation for why is it working this way?

Comment: @krulik This behaviour is defined by the Flexbox spec, see https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#auto-margins

Comment: There is definitely a `justify-self` attribute now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: @JakeWilson Thanks for the heads up! As of now, the document is a draft, I'll try to update the answer when it will be finalized.

Comment: After some more investigation, `justify-self` might not have anything to do with `flexbox` but rather is used with `css grids` but I'm not sure. I can't seem to get it to work in Chrome with flexbox.

Comment: What if I want one item to be on the left, and the other one in the center?

Comment: I tried justify-self it doesn't work yet, could not find much information on it either

Comment: "In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored" -taken from the mozilla docs on justify-self

Comment: This answer doesn't have the expected behaviour in IE11. Any workaround there? See this pen in IE11: http://cssdeck.com/labs/krmc3eao

Comment: I noticed the IE11 issue can be fixed by removing `justify-content: flex-end;` from the container, but keeping the `margin-right:auto;`

Comment: To extend on this answer, you can accomplish centering the first element, relative to the container but pushing the second element to flex-end, by using a "dummy" div of width 0: https://codepen.io/clintonc/pen/NJjQMY

Comment: Make sure that `container` is full width!

Comment: You can also have multiple child items be `justify-content: flex-start` but have the last child item be `justify-content: flex-end` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63329856/1069914

Answer (score 25):

AFAIK there is no property for that in the specs, but here is a trick I’ve been using:
set the container element ( the one with `display:flex` ) to `justify-content:space-around`
Then add an extra element between the first and second item and set it to `flex-grow:10` (or some other value that works with your setup)

Edit: if the items are tightly aligned it's a good idea to add `flex-shrink: 10;` to the extra element as well, so the layout will be properly responsive on smaller devices.

Comment: It does work without specifying width (at least it did in my situation)

Comment: Try `min-width: 0`

Answer (score 21):

If you aren't actually restricted to keeping all of these elements as sibling nodes you can wrap the ones that go together in another default flex box, and have the container of both use space-between.

```css
.space-between {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.default-flex {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-between">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="default-flex">
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you were doing the same thing with flex-start and flex-end reversed you just swap the order of the default-flex container and lone child.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar case by setting the inner item's style to `margin: 0 auto`.
Situation: My menu usually contains three buttons, in which case they need to be `justify-content: space-between`. But when there's only one button, it will now be center aligned instead of to the left.

Answer (score 1):

For those situations where width of the items you do want to `flex-end` is known, you can set their flex to "0 0 ##px" and set the item you want to `flex-start` with `flex:1`

This will cause the pseudo `flex-start` item to fill the container, just format it to `text-align:left` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Pavlo's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063808/1069914, you can have multiple child items `justify-content: flex-start` in their behavior but have the last item `justify-content: flex-end`

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 10px skyblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* set the second to last-child */
.container > :nth-last-child(2) {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width:150px">I should be at the end of the flex container (i.e. justify-content: flex-end)</div>
</div>
```