# How can you float: right in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an element that I want to float right, for example

```
<View style={{width: 300}}>
  <Text style={{backgroundColor: "#DDD"}}>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

How can the `Text` be floated / aligned to the right? Also, why does the `Text` take up the full space of the `View`, instead of just the space for "Hello"?

Comment: I wonder if you found an answer because the top 3 answers all say to use 3 different style attributes! `justifyContent`, `alignItems`, `alignSelf`. I wonder which is correct.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

> why does the Text take up the full space of the View, instead of just the space for "Hello"?

Because the `View` is a flex container and by default has [`flexDirection: 'column'`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexdirection) and [`alignItems: 'stretch'`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignitems), which means that its children should be stretched out to fill its width.

(Note, per [the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#display), that *all* components in React Native are `display: 'flex'` by default and that `display: 'inline'` does not exist at all. In this way, the default behaviour of a `Text` within a `View` in React Native differs from the default behaviour of `span` within a `div` on the web; in the latter case, the span would *not* fill the width of the `div` because a `span` is an inline element by default. There is no such concept in React Native.)

> How can the Text be floated / aligned to the right?

The [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) property doesn't exist in React Native, but there are *loads* of options available to you (with slightly different behaviours) that will let you right-align your text. Here are the ones I can think of:

#### 1. Use [`textAlign: 'right'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props.html#textalign) on the `Text` element

```
<View>
  <Text style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

(This approach doesn't change the fact that the `Text` fills the entire width of the `View`; it just right-aligns the text within the `Text`.)

#### 2. Use [`alignSelf: 'flex-end'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignself) on the `Text`

```
<View>
  <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

This shrinks the `Text` element to the size required to hold its content and puts it at the end of the cross direction (the horizontal direction, by default) of the `View`.

#### 3. Use [`alignItems: 'flex-end'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignitems) on the `View`

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
  <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

This is equivalent to setting `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` on all the `View`'s children.

#### 4. Use [`flexDirection: 'row'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexdirection) and [`justifyContent: 'flex-end'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#justifycontent) on the `View`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
  <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

`flexDirection: 'row'` sets the main direction of layout to be horizontal instead of vertical; `justifyContent` is just like `alignItems`, but controls alignment in the main direction instead of the cross direction.

#### 5. Use [`flexDirection: 'row'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexdirection) on the `View` and [`marginLeft: 'auto'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#marginleft) on the `Text`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Text style={{marginLeft: 'auto'}}>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

This approach is demonstrated, in the context of the web and real CSS, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063808/1709587.

#### 6. Use [`position: 'absolute'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#position) and [`right: 0`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#right) on the `Text`:

```
<View>
  <Text style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0}}>Hello, World!</Text>
</View>
```

Like in real CSS, this takes the `Text` "out of flow", meaning that its siblings will be able to overlap it and its vertical position will be at the top of the `View` by default (although you can explicitly set a distance from the top of the `View` using the `top` style property).

---

Naturally, which of these various approaches you want to use - and whether the choice between them even matters at all - will depend upon your precise circumstances.

Comment: None of these solutions work. :( My goal was to float a caption, and then the text coming from the left would go around it. Like this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19179424/1828637 - So I was  hoping to do: `<Text><Text>FLOAT TEXT</Text>multi line text here which wraps around float text`. Or same but with image like this: `<View><Text><Image />multi line text which wrap around float image</Text>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mark Amery!
I really like the fifth (5th) approach as I don't like to set a constant for the View/container's height as it auto-size itself.

Comment: No. 4 worked a treat for me. I suspect anyone having issues needs to look at how the View's are contained this can have a bearing on the flex layout of child elements.

Comment: Your answer is so detailed and full of great solutions, that it still holds up, 3 years after you gave it. Great job!

Answer (score 93):

You can directly specify the item's alignment, for example:

```
textright: {    
  alignSelf: 'flex-end',  
},
```

Comment: @goodniceweb You're confused; there *are* no inline elements in React Native. The only valid [`display`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#display) values are `'flex'` and `'none'`.

Comment: does not work if parent is flexDirection: 'row'

Answer (score 36):

For me setting `alignItems` to a parent did the trick, like:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 21):

You are not supposed to use floats in React Native. React Native leverages the flexbox to handle all that stuff.

In your case, you will probably want the container to have an attribute

```
justifyContent: 'flex-end'
```

And about the text taking the whole space, again, you need to take a look at your container.

Here is a link to really great guide on flexbox: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 21):

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
  <Text>
  Some Text
  </Text>
</View>
```

`flexDirection`: If you want to move horizontally (row) or vertically (column)

`justifyContent`: the direction you want to move.

Comment: A bit misleading; [`justifyContent`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#justifycontent) doesn't choose a *direction* per se; it offers a bunch of options about how things are positioned and spaced along the main flex direction.

Answer (score 6):

Use `flex: 1` and `alignItems: 'flex-end'` in View styling. Make sure to include `flex: 1`. That is the key to make the element **float right**

Answer (score 3):

using flex

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30, color:'#9394B3' }}>left</Text>
                  <Text style={{ flex:1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color:'#1D2359', textAlign:'right' }}>right</Text>
               </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float:right in react native using flex:

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
</View>
```

for more detail: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction

Comment: This just repeats an approach I'd already posted (it's option 4 in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47961683/1709587)) and I don't see any added value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just style the text with alignSelf: 'flex-end':

```
<View style={{width: 300}}>
  <Text style={{backgroundColor: "#DDD", alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
flowRight: {
flex:1,
justifyContent: 'end',
alignContent: 'end',
},
});

Then call styles.flowRight in your style

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).