# how to style text component to the right of view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

[image]

Hi, I want the date shown above to be on the right side of the view, however am unable to do it, could anyone suggest anything?

My code:

```
 <View style={{padding: 10}}>
      {props.data.data.content != undefined &&
        props.data.data.content != null &&
        props.data.data.content.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                padding: 10,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                elevation: 3,
                margin: '2%',
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}>
              <View>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/atbirth.jpg')}
                  style={{height: 40, width: 50}}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              </View>
              <View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Text
                    key={item.id}
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }}>
                    {item.name}
                  </Text>

                  <View >
                    <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: 12,}}>
                      {item.display_date}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  {item.vaccine_list.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15}}>
                          {i.name},
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    );
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </View>
```

Let me know, where am going wrong and how do I implement the above shown behavior, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: This does not solve your problem ؟<Text style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: 12, float: right}}>
                      {item.display_date}
                    </Text>

Comment: no, react native does not have float

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030050/how-can-you-float-right-in-react-native

Comment: no none of these helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align your elements by using Flex.

```
 <View style={{padding: 10}}>
      {props.data.data.content != undefined &&
        props.data.data.content != null &&
        props.data.data.content.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                padding: 10,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                elevation: 3,
                margin: '2%',
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}>
              <View>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/atbirth.jpg')}
                  style={{height: 40, width: 50}}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
                  <Text
                    key={item.id}
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }}>
                    {item.name}
                  </Text>

                  <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: 12,}}>
                      {item.display_date}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  {item.vaccine_list.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15}}>
                          {i.name},
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    );
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </View>
```

Using Flex you are going to take all the available space and then you will be able to align the date to the right