# Positioning of elements inside the Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having an issue with the position of an element inside the navigation menu:

```
<header class="main-header">
  <a href="" class="logo"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/i/logo/rebrand/ppcom.svg" alt="Paypal logo" /></a>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Buy</a></li>   
      <li><a href="">Sell</a></li> 
      <li><a href="">Send</a></li> 
      <li><a href="">Business</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="#" class="">Log in</a>
    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

The `div.button` is the element that I'm having an issue with. I used `flex` to position the elements inside the header. But I have a problem with the position of the `div.button`, I can't position it to the right. I inserted a padding to the left to move it but it's just a bad workaround.

You can check my work in CodePen: http://codepen.io/marcvs/pen/JRmQjx

I'm a newbie when it comes to Web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real `justify-child` option, but you can use the `margin-left: auto;` trick:

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Also, related: [How to justify a single flexbox item (override justify-content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621650/how-to-justify-a-single-flexbox-item-override-justify-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
**flex display** is a flexible layout.
By giving the right value as a percentage, it is also responsive to the application.

```css
.button {
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  right:3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
     <a href="#" class="">Log in</a>
     <a href="#">Sign up</a>
</div>
```